# Throwing exception in initialisation list?

Tags: c++, class, methods

I have the following code:

In Game.h:

```
mtm::Dimensions dimensions;
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Character>> board;
```

In Game.cpp:

```
Game::Game(int height, int width) : dimensions(height, width), board(height * width, nullptr) 
{
    if (height <= 0 || width <= 0) {
        throw mtm::IllegalArgument();
    }
}
```

But as you may notice I'm throwing the error too late, if `height * width` is smaller than 0 then a bad_alloc will be thrown instead of `IllegalArgument`, How may I fix this?

Is there a way to throw an exception in the initialisation list?

Comment: Move the check into `mtm::Dimensions`'s constructor, if you can.Solves your problem and seems to be a more logical place to validate dimensions.

Comment: I can't do that @user4581301

Comment: Rats.How about adding a helper function that does the check and returns the product of `height` and `width`. `board(height * width, nullptr)` becomes `board(helper(height, width), nullptr)`

Comment: @user4581301 and that helper function returns the IllegalArgument? sound ok but is there a way to do this without helper function? (I heard it's possible)

Comment: In the initializer list you have to be initializing something. I can't think of anything that would be simpler and easier to understand than the helper function. Doesn't mean it doesn't exist, though. People here come up with stuff that blows my mind daily

Comment: Psst. You could use a macro https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/HZqAFL

Comment: `: dimensions(height <= 0 || width <= 0 ? throw mtm::IllegalArgument() : height, width)` would do it, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you cannot do the check in `mtm::Dimensions`, it really should be there, you can use a helper function:

```
int throw_if_not_positive(int x) {
    if (x <= 0) throw mtm::IllegalArgument();
    return x;
}

Game::Game(int height, int width) : 
    dimensions(throw_if_not_positive(height),
               throw_if_not_positive(width)), 
    board(height * width, nullptr) 
{
}
```

Or use `unsigned`, or use

```
struct positive_int {
     int value;
     positive_int(int x) : value(x) {
        if (x <= 0)  throw mtm::IllegalArgument();
     }
     operator int(){ return value; }
};

Game::Game(positive_int height, positive_int width) : 
    dimensions(height,width), 
    board(height * width, nullptr) 
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm curious does you solution have advantages over user4581301 solution ?

Comment: What I like about this is it catches the error ahead of `dimension` so it fails early without wasted effort constructing the dimension.

Comment: @BigSur I prefer to have empty constructors and I prefer to have such checks in types rather than in functions. If I could choose I would do the check when constructing `dimensions` but as you ruled that out, i'd go for the last. For your last comment I dont understand what you mean, in the first example the body of the constructor is empty

Comment: @BigSur oh sorry, user4581301 already made the edit. Its already late here ;)

Comment: It seemed the logical thing to do. It was such an obvious brain-fade. My brain didn't even register that the code was still there until BigSur pointed it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can first catch the `bad_alloc` thrown in the construction of `board`, and then throw your own custom exception:

```
Game::Game(int height, int width) try : dimensions(height, width), board(height * width, nullptr) 
{
    if (height <= 0 || width <= 0) {
        throw mtm::IllegalArgument();
    }
}
catch(...)  // or specifically bad_alloc
{
   throw mtm::IllegalArgument();  // or some other custom exception
}
```

Here's another (better) answer that's based on your own suggestion in the comments:

```
Game::Game(int height, int width) : 
  dimensions(height, width), 
  board((height * width > 0 ? height * width : throw mtm::IllegalArgument()), 
        nullptr) 
{
  // ...
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://www.godbolt.org/z/db2dKt).

Comment: I want to leave bad_alloc when there is no enough memory and not to replace every bad_alloc with IllegalArgument()

Comment: Oh, I see. Not sure if there's a way to do that without a helper function.

Comment: Someone suggested (and deleted) Game::Game(int height, int width):board((height <=0 || width <=0) ? throw IllegalArgument() (Matrix...) are you familiar with this?

Comment: That definitely looks possible. Did you try it out? If it works, you can post an answer.

Comment: See? There's always something even though this one's not all that mind-blowing. Now let's try that with fifty pages of macros and templates!

Answer (score 0):

Insert a helper function to validate the `height` and `width`.

```
size_t helper(int height, int width)
{
    if (height <= 0 || width <= 0) {
        throw mtm::IllegalArgument();
    }
    return height * width;
}

Game::Game(int height, int width) : 
    dimensions(height, width), 
    board(helper(height, width), nullptr) 
{
}
```